# Display information against current selected link and show in a modal in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, modal-dialog

i need your help
[image]

the problem is: on the attached image the last option is "Detail" when user click on detail the modal pop up with the job tittle and description, but the problem that i'm facing is by clicking on detail option the modal pop up with all the titles and all the job descriptions, but i need just the click one details.

[image]

Comment: show the code you have written in modal

Comment: <td> <asp:HyperLink ID="hypDetail" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" %>Detail </asp:HyperLink> </td> </tr>

Comment: modal popup by this link {Detail}.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403979/open-modal-dialog-when-an-hyperlinks-is-cliked if you need more clarity. Display only the needed data in the modal. For example if you want to display the content for 'Web developer', append only the data for web developer. Filter the Query in such a way only a particular job which is clicked gets displayed.
A sample query 'Select Jobid, PostTitle, PostDescription, LastDate where Jobid=1 from Job_Posting'.

Comment: Its not an answer, its a comment. So add it as a comment

Comment: <td>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="hypDetail" runat="server" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal" %>Detail </asp:HyperLink>

</td>

                                    </tr>

Comment: by clicking this Detail link modal will pop up, but getting all the titles and description but i want just the click one.

Comment: I cant comment. So I gave an answer. Anyway I can edit it and update my answer.

Comment: Can I get the code used to display the data in modal

Comment: data-target = "#myModal "
this is my modal name you need modal code ?

Comment: <---Modal Header--->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
       <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Detail Information</h4></div>

Comment: <div class="modal-body">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None"  CssClass="tbl-data"AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <Columns> <asp:TemplateField> <ItemTemplate>
     <table> <tr><td > <h3><%# Eval("PostTitle") %></h3></td></tr>
         <tr><td><div><p><asp:Literal ID="litPostDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PostDescription") %>'></asp:Literal></p></div></td></tr>
          </tabl> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> </Columns>
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid-header" />
  <FooterStyle CssClass="grid-footer" />
  </asp:GridView>  </div> </div>

Comment: <div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apply Now</button>
     </div> </div> </div> </div>

Comment: What is your need actually. what I meant to share is how data is appended to the modal. Not how u declare the modal.

Comment: ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spGetRecordFrmJobPosting] -- 8

As

Select Jobid, PostTitle, PostDescription, LastDate from Job_Posting

Comment: this is class code of web page ....

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Datalayer dl = new Datalayer();
        DataTable dt = dl.spGetRecordFrmJobPosting();
        gvCareers.DataSource = dt;
        gvCareers.DataBind();

       GridView1.DataSource = dt;
       GridView1.DataBind();
       
    }